# FTP PowerShell Setup - Advanced Settings

Tags: powershell, scripting, ftp

I am making a basic PowerShell script to setup an FTP site.

I can get all the 'basics' done but cant figure out how to change any of the 'advanced settings' - i.e. Max Connections, Control Channel Timeout etc. These are the settings that you can find by opening the Advanced Settings under Manage FTP Site in IIS Manager.

Any advice would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[First google hit by Shay Levi back in 2008](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/ba094c6a-f348-4dfb-9745-c97a9fdbb40b/change-maxconnection-setting-in-iis-with-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell)

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty '/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name="Default Web Site"]' -Name Limits -Value @{MaxConnections=<yourValue>}
```

[You can find these properties in the IIS Reference doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/ftpserver/connections)

Comment: Thanks - you must be a much better Googler then I...

Comment: The more you work in a particular area, the better your searching gets. Keep at it!

Comment: Although upon trying this (and variations) I cant seem to make it work for the FTP site